# after login in - customer is taken back to the shopping cart (where the product they selected is) INSTEAD of the 1st step of the checkout

Tags: checkout

Please help - I can't figure this out and customers are not able to place orders...The interesting thing is that everything works the way it suppose to in Firefox but **NOT in Chrome**...

What happens is this:

1. Customer selects a product and goes through the steps up till the login page.
2. At the login page - they put in their login credentials (user Id and password) and click on LOGIN
3. This is where it happens in Chrome (**it works fine in Firefox**) - instead of the shopping cart showing the 1st step of the CHECKOUT -  1
   Billing Information (Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.) - *the customer is taken back to the SHOPPING CART* where it shows the product they selected...
4. Now they have to click on the "Proceed to Checkout" button but nothing happens after the first click! (it just refreshes the same page). Then - they have to click that button again and are taken to a page which displays this:

> SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY
>
> ```
> You have no items in your shopping cart.
>
> Click here to continue shopping.
> ```

Please help me - I am clueless! I haven't changed anything other than upgrading the Cloud hosting package to a better one (with more resources).

Comment: Did you figure out the issue ?